# Selenium Connection Error

Tags: python, firefox, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Has anyone run across this error before? I just started getting this error on monday. Why is it having issues with connecting?

Selenium will open the browser but will not plug in the url.

```
  C:\Python34\python.exe "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 4.0.5\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py" --multiproc --client 127.0.0.1 --port 49660 --file //HAL1/FTP-Directories/Comal-County/comal.py
  pydev debugger: process 5564 is connecting

  Connected to pydev debugger (build 139.1547)
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 4.0.5\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 2217, in       <module>
      globals = debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None)
    File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 4.0.5\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1643, in run
      pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
    File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition4.0.5\helpers\pydev\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
      exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc) 
    File "//HAL1/FTP-Directories/Comal-County/comal.py", line 7, in <module>
      driver = webdriver.Firefox();
    File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py", line 59, in __init__
      self.binary, timeout),
    File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\extension_connection.py", line 47, in __init__
      self.binary.launch_browser(self.profile)
    File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\firefox_binary.py", line 66, in launch_browser
      self._wait_until_connectable()
    File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\firefox_binary.py", line 105, in       _wait_until_connectable
      raise WebDriverException("Can't load the profile. Profile "
  selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Can't load the profile. Profile Dir: %s If you specified a       log_file in the FirefoxBinary constructor, check it for details.
```

Code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox();
driver.get("http://www.google.com")
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a **compatibility issue** between `selenium` and `Firefox`.

Upgrade your `Firefox` to the latest version (36 at the moment).

And upgrade `selenium` to the latest version (2.45 at the moment):

```
pip install --upgrade selenium
```

Comment: Thank you, what program do you use to execute that code?

Comment: Im familar with pip. Im just trying to get it to open. Do you use thee Python Shell or Cmd window?

Comment: @DJHowarth sure, use `cmd` since you are on windows.

Comment: Good to go. Thank you @alecxe

Comment: That didn't solve the issue. Firefox 37.0.2 / selenium 2.45.0

Comment: @NimaSoroush Well, firefox 37 and selenium 2.45 have compatibility issues too, upgrade selenium to the currently latest 2.46.

Answer (score 1):

This is a frequent occurrence when there is a 'major version' FF release; it's also been happening recently with FF42.

A temporary solution is to [remove all FF profiles](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profile-manager-create-and-remove-firefox-profiles); you may need to do this repeatedly.

Longer-term, the next release of Selenium should address the issue; a new Selenium release usually follows hot on the heels of a new FF major version.